# Which algorithm can be applied to build a complex tree of children?

Tags: python, algorithm, hierarchy

I have an 'Entity' object, this Entity contains an entity_type attribute, in the simplest form:

```py
   class Entity:
       def __init__(entity_type: str):
           self.entity_type = entity_type
```

I have supported entity types of the following:

```py
    {'entity_a', 'entity_b', 'entity_c', 'entity_d'}
```

I need to construct a potentially unlimited (wide) tree of these entities, there is only 1 constraint:

entity_a can only contain children of entity_b, entity_c and entity_d,

entity_b can only contain children of entity_c, entity_d,

entity_c can only contain children of entity_d,

entity_d cannot have children

entity_a tho could have 50 entity_b in which it could have 50 entity_c in which could have 50 entity_d.

The depth here is a maximum of 4 tiers deep, however the width can be unlimited

What approach / algorithm(s) can be implemented for this problem? to provide a relatively simple way of constructing various hierarchies of entities?

Comment: Only 1 constraint, for some large value of 1.

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I don't see where you're stuck.  Also, I'm not sure what input you have to drive generation of the tree.  Do you need to check a given input for tree violations?  It's hard to tell, since you have yet to attack the problem on your own -- sometimes, code can make up for lack of problem specification.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the simplest thing that could possibly work.

```
class InvalidEntityType(Exception):
    pass

class Entity:
    def __init__(entity_type: str):
        self.entity_type = entity_type
        self.entities = []

    def add_entity(self, entity):
        if self.entity_type < entity.entity_type:
            self.entities.append(entity)
        else:
            raise InvalidEntityType(
                "Entity of type {0} cannot contain entities of type {1}".format(
                    self.entity_type, entity.entity_type))
```